# CiviDiscount Automatic Discounts Not Working on Events

Tags: cividiscount

Using CiviDiscount 3.3, CiviCRM 4.7.1.9 and Wordpress 4.7.5.

When attempting to create an automatic discount for members of type, with status new, current, and grace period or even any current status, I am unable to get a discount to automatically appear on any membership or event pages. The code I created works, but won't automatically apply for members. This also means anyone with the code, even non-members can use it. What am I doing wrong?
[image]

Comment: Can you post a screen shot of the discount code setup screen?

Comment: added :) -  I should note, honestly, I just want a universal 10% off code for current members to be used anywhere however, I am willing to recreate it for each event if I have to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your setup looks correct. This should provide a 10% discount to members. They must be logged in to their WordPress account in order to receive the discount otherwise the system will not recognize them as members.

I recommend using a randomly generated code. This makes it difficult for random visitors to guess the code.

Comment: Something else must be happening.  The automatic discount is not applying to any of the member accounts we have.  Even the test member account we use.

Comment: Turns out there must be something seriously wrong with one of my administrator accounts - when I use the main one to create the discount - I run into no problems.  Thanks for the tip on the random code and for your help.